# Python - unreliable shell command execution? Problems running ir-ctl commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command-line, raspberry-pi

I'm building simple automation for my stereo amplifier using Raspberry Pi and I'm having some problems with executing shell commands from python. My script is supposed to listen for events from spotify client and change selected source on my amplifier. I have IR blaster connected to my Raspberry Pi which I control using `ir-ctl` tool. It works perfectly from command line, eg when I run this:

```
ir-ctl -d /dev/lirc0 -S necx:0x856a24
```

Source on my amplifier is changed to AUX. Then I can run:

```
ir-ctl -d /dev/lirc0 -S necx:0x856a8c
```

To change it back to CD. This works 100% successfully when ran manually from shell. The device is configured through `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx
```

Now I want to use that in a python script that listens for events from my spotify client and change the source according to device selected in spotify.
And here's the problem - the script seems to execute the command but sometimes nothing happens, the source is not changed. I'm super confused about that since I can see stdout confirming successful command execution.

Here's my script with amplifier operations:

```
def sourceCD():
    print("Changing source to CD")
    runCode('0x856a8c')

def sourceAUX():
    print("Changing source to AUX")
    runCode('0x856a24')

def runCode(code):
    necCommand = 'necx:{}'.format(code)
    #result = subprocess.run(["ir-ctl", "-d","/dev/lirc0","-S", necCommand], capture_output=True, check=True)
    result = subprocess.run(['ir-ctl -d /dev/lirc0 -S necx:{}'.format(code)], shell=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
    print(result)
```

And here's my listener script:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    event = json.loads(message)["event"]
    print('Received event: ', event)

    if event == "contextChanged":
        print("Reacting to changed context")
        sourceAUX()

    if event == "inactiveSession":
        print("reacting to inactive session")
        sourceCD()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://192.168.0.41:24879/events",
                          on_message = on_message,
                          on_error = on_error,
                          on_close = on_close)
    ws.run_forever()
```

I can see in console output that shell scripts is executed every time I change spotify device:

```
Aug 23 23:09:59 raspberrypi python[4571]: Received event:  inactiveSession
Aug 23 23:09:59 raspberrypi python[4571]: reacting to inactive session
Aug 23 23:09:59 raspberrypi python[4571]: Changing source to CD
Aug 23 23:09:59 raspberrypi python[4571]: CompletedProcess(args=['ir-ctl', '-d', '/dev/lirc0', '-S', 'necx:0x856a8c'], returncode=0, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')
Aug 23 23:10:01 raspberrypi python[4571]: Received event:  contextChanged
Aug 23 23:10:01 raspberrypi python[4571]: Reacting to changed context
Aug 23 23:10:01 raspberrypi python[4571]: Changing source to AUX
Aug 23 23:10:02 raspberrypi python[4571]: CompletedProcess(args=['ir-ctl', '-d', '/dev/lirc0', '-S', 'necx:0x856a24'], returncode=0, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')
```

However the source is not updated on my amplifier. This is super confusing to me, why does it work 100% times when run directly in the shell and being flaky when run from python?

It's worth mentioning that alternating these two:

```
    #result = subprocess.run(["ir-ctl", "-d","/dev/lirc0","-S", necCommand], capture_output=True, check=True)
result = subprocess.run(['ir-ctl -d /dev/lirc0 -S necx:{}'.format(code)], shell=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
```

does seem to impact success rate, which only further confuses me. I'm a programmer but python is a new language to me, would appreciate any help with that riddle.

I run my script in virtualenv, Python 3.7.3.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to blame `ir-ctl` if you do have logs saying exitcode zero. Maybe add some code to re-query if `/dev/lirc0` is actually set to the new value. If it isn't the right variable then try setting it again.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. The device only allows me to transmit, can I somehow read from the device file? I don't have much knowledge in that area.
From `ir-ctl -f -d /dev/lirc0`: 
Receive features /dev/lirc0:
 - Device cannot receive
Send features /dev/lirc0:
 - Device can send raw IR
 - IR scancode encoder
 - Set carrier
 - Set duty cycle.
-------

Also, is it possible that using virtualenv (and therefore python 3 instead of system default python 2.7) breaks something inside ir-ctl?

Comment: Hmm the tool seems to be written in C so I guess not likely to be influenced by python version https://github.com/cz172638/v4l-utils/blob/master/utils/ir-ctl/ir-ctl.c

Comment: You it works sometimes but not always? are there any circumstances under which you feel it works more often than others? What is the ratio between it working and not working?

Comment: In general it seems to work for a couple of runs of the command, then it breaks, then it works again. Depending on the variant it's something like 50% time when it's ok or lower.

Comment: Running my defined python functions from command line seems to be working perfectly, eg when I run `python amp_operations.py sourceCD` it consistently changes the source. That means there's something wrong in the web socket listener script. Any ideas what could go wrong here? Maybe something with threads? I don't know much about them in python.

Comment: I have added websocket code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem not in the Python code but in the nature of IR signals processing by your receiver (stereo amplifier). It may not be enough to send just one command and you need to send several at once. Instead of

```
ir-ctl -d /dev/lirc0 -S necx:0x856a24
```

send

```
ir-ctl -d /dev/lirc0 -S necx:0x856a24 -S necx:0x856a24 -S necx:0x856a24
```

From [ir-ctl - a swiss-knife tool to handle raw IR and to set lirc options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ir-ctl.1.html):

> -S, --scancode=PROTOCOL:SCANCODE
> Send the IR scancode in the protocol  specified.  The  protocol  must  one  of  the
> protocols listed below, followed by a colon and the scancode number. **If this option
> is specified multiple times, send all scancodes in-order with a 125ms  gap  between
> them.** The gap length can be modified with --gap.